# import text file getting command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, import

here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    country       CHAR(2),
    city_ascii    VARCHAR(100),
    city          VARCHAR(255),
    region        CHAR(2),
    population    INT UNSIGNED,
    latitude      DECIMAL(10, 6),
    longitude     DECIMAL(10, 6),
    INDEX idx_lat_long (latitude, longitude),
    INDEX idx_country (country),
    INDEX idx_region (region)
);
```

I'm trying to import a text file to my database following tutorial [here](http://jeffbrand.net/2012/05/importing-maxminds-world-cities-data-to-mysql/).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'worldcitiespop.txt' INTO TABLE cities
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(country, city_ascii, city, region, population, latitude, longitude);
```

but I'm getting the following error message.

```
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: why do you not read the manual. A limk to the manual can be found in he article you are referencinng to.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL Documentation on `Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data-local.html)

> If LOAD DATA LOCAL is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:
>
> ```
> ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
> ```

How ? The server option [local_infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) must be disabled. Check your my.cnf for [load_infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile). If you are using a web hosting service, they may or may not allow it. For example, you cannot do that with Amazon RDS for MySQL. You might be able to get away with using MySQL in Amazon EC2. Check with your administrators in that respect.